# IFTweetLabel major issue for long URL

Tags: iphone, url, uilabel, detection

Following opensource is mostly used for hyperlink urls, phone no. etc/
https://github.com/clawoo/IFTweetLabel

But there is one major issue in this open source that it never hyper link if it is too long (more than 1 line)

I have tried using following url and it only hyperlinked first line instead of 3lines
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_wuODgRtiCUY/TO2W2EqC2hI/AAAAAAAAAEA/PbwTm9Cl8As/s1600/Shining-Apple-Logo-759135.jpg

Please post some solution or any other good open source.

Thanks

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a very long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the solution.

comment out the code:

//BOOL breakWidth = NO;

```
/*if (currentSize.width > frame.size.width)
{
// the width of the text in the frame caused the line to break
    //NSLog(@"------ scanText = '%@', currentSize = %@", scanText,       
    //NSStringFromCGSize(currentSize));
      breakWidth = YES;

  }*/
```

Now it will not check for the width of string (or end of 1 line ) and will check the whole string until it get the new line character.

Comment: Okay, but if you comment out //BOOL breakWidth = NO; it breaks several other lines of code in IFTweet.  Specifically line 278 if (breakLine || breakWidth) {

How do you account for that?